# Oracle 11g slow export

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, export

My question is about slowness while doing an export. Is there a reason why tables that have 0 row takes 3-4 seconds per table while a table with 30000+ rows take a fraction of a second?

Comment: You may want to mention how exactly you are measuring this.

Comment: Actually just looking at the screen while the export is running. it takes a few seconds for the tables with 0 row and tables that contains rows it goes very fast

Comment: I don't think this is very scientific. The console output is not necessarily synchronous with the datapump background jobs.